# Why garbage collector will destroy object that still has reference to it?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have following code:

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SomeClass oneInstance = new SomeClass();

 oneInstance.otherInstance = new SomeClass();

 oneInstance = null;
 }
}

class SomeClass {
 public SomeClass otherInstance;
}
```

I know that JVM will start garbage collector on both of the created objects, but what happens with otherInstance reference? It should still point to the second object

Comment: If the `oneInstance` is garbage collected, then it no longer exists, ergo, it can't reference anything.  Therefor, nothing references `otherInstance` anymore and it too can be garbage collected.

Comment: No, @AJNeufeld, your proposed dupe target asks a different question, about whether an object is protected from garbage collection if it holds a reference to another object.  It nevertheless seems likely that the present question is a dupe; I'll see whether I can find a better target.